# Given a function with symbols, convert symbols into function variables

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

Let's say that you have a function with symbols, i.e.

```
f[x] = x^2 +a[1]
```

I want to define a new function

```
g[x,a[1]] = x^2 +a[1]
```

Comment: `f` returning `a[1]` is fraught with potential problems. If `a` is defined before a call to `f` then you will get unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` returning `a[1]` is fraught with potential problems. If `a` is defined before a call to `f` then you will get unexpected behavior.

```
fBadIdea[x_] := x^2 + a[1]
```

Then

```
fBadIdea[2]
```

> ```
> 4 + a[1]
> ```

This seems fine.  However, you have a problem with

```
a = {1, 2};
fBadIdea[2]
```

> ```
> 4 + {1, 2}[1]
> ```

It is best practice to return [Formal Symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotationalAlphabetCharacters.html#36809601) for non-scoped symbols; see docs for keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

```
f[x_] := x^2 + \[FormalA][1]
```

Now

```
f[2]
```

> [image]

> ```
> 4 + \[FormalA][1]
> ```

but any attempt to assign to `\[FormalA]` is blocked so you don't get unexpected results.

[image]

For `g`

```
g[x_, a_] := f[x] /. \[FormalA][1] -> a
```

and

```
g[2, c]
```

> ```
> 4 + c
> ```

as required.

Hope this helps.